# What are the assumptions of repeated measures ANCOVA?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, experiment-design, assumptions, ancova

In my experiment I have a randomly allocated control and experimental group, as well as pretest and posttest.
To control for baseline differences, I saw that conducting an ANCOVA is recommended. However, two assumptions of the ANCOVA are that 1) observations are independent from each other and 2) covariate variables and independent variables are not related.
I thought: Since pretest and posttest are within-subject 1) cannot be true. Since I expect that A affects B, the pretest of A will also be related to B, therefore 2) cannot be true.

Therefore, I wanted to conduct a repeated measures ANCOVA in R.

However, what are the assumptions of repeated measures ANCOVA?
I cant find them anywhere and if I take the assumptions of repeated measures ANOVA, I don't know whether to split the data in time AND group to test for outliers and normality. And for sphericity I have no clue. Has anyone an idea?